# How to get the child index in a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form (I'm using twitter bootstrap and formtastic), where Member the parent model and Caregiver is the child model.

So I have this in the `new` action of the MembersController...

```
@member = Member.new
3.times {@member.caregivers.build}
```

Then, in the form, I have this...

```
<%= f.fields_for :caregivers do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'caregiver_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

**How can I access the child index in the _caregiver_fields.html.erb partial?**

I need it because in the form, I would like to add the number of the nested model, for example...

```
Member Name: _________

1. Caregiver Name: ______
   Additional fields...

2. Caregiver Name: ______
   Additional fields...

3. Caregiver Name: ______
   Additional fields...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this task by using `index` method from `Array` and local variable in partial:

```
<%= render 'caregiver_fields', 
  :locals => { f: builder, index: @member.caregivers.index[builder] } %>
```

In partial it will be something like this:

```
<h><%= index %></h>
```

Comment: thanks, but I get `undefined method [] for #<Enumerator:0x007f83d474ed70>` I think you got an extra bracket

Comment: yes, still even without the extra bracket, exactly as it is above, i get `undefined method [] for #<Enumerator:0x000000079e2198>`

Comment: @leonel, as I understood from you snippet code the caregivers should be an array

Comment: Try `@member.caregivers.index(builder.object)` rather than `@member.caregivers.index[builder]`.